# jQuery order of execution, document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, execution, document-ready

When calling a selector within a document ready function, the first call returns the element `el.length == 1` the second call returns an empty set `el.length == 0`. Can anyone clarify what is going on here?

http://jsfiddle.net/47gNX/

It seems my map DOM element is being emptied in the _.init function i have created...

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle to elaborate it? Can't reproduce. http://jsfiddle.net/47gNX/

Comment: OK so now i have created a VERY detailed fiddle of what im doing: http://jsfiddle.net/47gNX/

Comment: Running your fiddle returns 1 1 document ready 2... No '0'

Comment: one possible reason could be between the first and second calls there are other script executions that is removing that element

Comment: Post your code here, and include all relevant detail. But the jsFiddle you posted is the same as the one that @xdazz posted, so I don't know what you're trying to prove.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: That isn't possible unless the calls are asynchronous.

Comment: @cookiemonster in the fiddle it is not possible... but if OP has the 2 dom ready handlers in different files then there might be some other script executing between them

Comment: I worked it out: when setting up the map, that clears the DOM inside the map element. If i cache the markers before i init the map everything is fine!! **face slap**

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I think I misunderstood what you meant by "other script executions". Yes, other code running between the two calls could do it.